# How do I receive and store data input in C#?

Tags: c#, input, visual-studio-express

Basically I'm still in the starting phase, and I know how to use `Console.WriteLine`, but I have no idea on how to have it read input from the user.

For example, I'd want a user to be able to type in a pair of numbers, then return the result.

My goal  is a program that receives input , then combines them and returns the average.

This is all in Visual C# Express 2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
```

that will return you a string of the user's input. Check out MSDN for documentation on the Console class. Also look at the Convert class.

```
int num = Convert.ToInt32(input);
```

Good luck new coder.

Answer (score 1):

First create a variable to store the user input, like this:

```
int variablenameofyourchoice = 0;
```

Then take input like this and store it in your variable name:

```
variablenameofyourchoice = int.parse(Console.ReadLine())
```

Then do whatever you want with that variable. If you want two numbers do this twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very general topic with a lot of answers, but [Console.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) is one counterpart of Console.WriteLine.  It reads a line of text from standard in.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Console.ReadLine()` or `Console.Read()` in the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console_members.aspx)

Comment: Ok, I see how to obtain data. How do I actually store it? Like, if I want to return a solution that's based on several pieces of data that have been input?

Comment: @Slateboard - for temporary storage, in variables or properties. You might want to go through a few tutorials or pick up an introductory C# book.